What does "cycle out" mean in Megazone 23 Part III?
Throughout the two episodes of Megazone 23 Part III, there were a number of references to "cycle out", the "cycle education" and the "Cycle Center" being made, but without an explanation of what they stand for. I've gathered most of these references, all of which are from episode 1, with a timestamp attached to the end of each dialogue as follows:

The Information Supervisory Department E=X has examined the numbers, and has decided to accelerate the re-evaluation of the cycle education program and the mental health program. [04:11]


Let's have a party, a cycle out party for Eiji. [07:34]


But you don't think it's funny that someone who's cycled out is working part time? [13:06]


Ryo, that's not the reason why you cycled out, is it? [14:06]


They only thing I know is that she got cycled out on the same day as me. [16:42]


Nope! If you cycle out someday, I'll be nice to you. [21:06]


I met Sion at an audition. He encouraged me to cycle out. [36:31]

If we piece the information together, it seems that "cycling out" is a choice and carries some kind of prestige and stability as a full-time job.
This question has also been asked on Reddit and touched upon in this blog post, which I'll quote the relevant lines below:

Either a military term for leaving when your tour of service had ended, or being callously replaced in a job with where you're seen as a disposable worker.


Meanwhile, we see a lot of talk of "cycling out" & the like without ever getting an explanation, but a quick line in Episode 2 vaguely indicates that it's nothing more than a futuristic way of saying that someone has graduated to adulthood, as in finishing school.

However, the answers contradict my narrowed-down scope of possible definitions of "cycle out", and they do not tie it to the "cycle education" and the "Cycle Center", which I think are closely related.
So, what exactly is "cycling out" in the settings of Megazone 23? Is this ever expanded on in any material outside the OVA anime, like the Megazone 23: Blue Garland video game?

I searched using the Japanese term サイクルアウト, and there's only 1 blog that interpreted it as 就職 without official reference. The rest is related to a baseball term that I believe is irrelevant. Other than that, I didn't find any discussion in Japanese about this term...

I always forget to check for Japanese sites also. 就職 (getting a job) would certainly fit with my interpretation, but I wonder why they'd make up new vocabularies for such a basic notion in modern society.
